# Using Firebase Authentication with Google App Engine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, polymer, firebase-authentication

I'm a newbie so any help appreciated.

I've created an app/service using Google App Engine (node) that returns a simple 'hello world' response, see https://resumetemplatesconverter.appspot.com/

I've also got a Polymer web app that uses Firebase Authentication for sign up, sign in, sign out, etc.

Question is, what is the best way to configure the Google App Engine app/service so that only users authenticated with the Polymer web app can use it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain the scenario more detail. You want to direct the user to the sign-up page, and if signed up then let the user to use app ? or how ? Check this link Fairbase authenticate api, that may heps you to integrate you for sign-up page https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web

Comment: Hi I just want authenticated users (those which have signed up and are signed in) from the website to be able to use the Google App Engine app/service, no-one else. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: @HalloweenMan Would be nice to accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Absolutely, I tried it and it worked brilliantly. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: @HalloweenMan Did you sign in only using google sign in or other method provided in firebase auth? how did you verify the tokens other than google sign in tokens you receive from firebase (lets say normal email password sign in) on you app engine service? Were you able to make your app engine apis authenticated (using firebase auth)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase (Authorization Server) sends a token (Access Token) back to the client (browser).

The client now makes a request to your app engine service (Resource Server) with that token.

What you need to do is **to check if the token is valid and if it is valid, return that secret data**.

The **OAuth 2.0** spec doesn't clearly define the interaction between a Resource Server and Authorization Server for access token validation:

> Access token attributes and the methods used to access protected resources are beyond the scope of this specification and are defined by companion specifications.

So for each authentication service (Google, Facebook, GitHub, etc.) you use, you have to look up how to validate the Access Token.

Example:

**Google**

Request (from your app engine backend)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123
```

Response

```
{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

You can make this plain request from your backend server but it would be better using one of the [Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/)

See here for more info regarding [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

Comment: Thanks very much @JFathi the link to Google's Auth with a backend includes specifics for Nodejs (via npm google-auth-library), PHP, Python, Java which is what I needed.